# How do I remove a trailing slash? The current htaccess code I have isn't working

Tags: .htaccess

I want to remove the trailing slash so that

```
https://www.hooklust.com/oo.a/
```

looks like

```
https://www.hooklust.com/oo.a
```

(the dir oo.a contains an index.php file)

I found the following tutorial for removing trailing slashes from URLs, but I still end up with a trailing slash:

```
https://www.danielmorell.com/guides/htaccess-seo/redirects/https-www-and-trailing-slash
```

The code:

```
#### Force HTTPS://WWW and remove trailing / from files ####
## Turn on rewrite engine
RewriteEngine on

# Remove trailing slash from non-filepath urls
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /(.+)/$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ https://www.example.com/%1 [R=301,L]

# Include trailing slash on directory 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.+)/$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ https://www.example.com/$1/ [R=301,L]

# Force HTTPS and WWW 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.(.*)$ [OR,NC]
RewriteCond %{https} off  
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

I took everything else out of the htaccess file to make sure nothing else was adding the slash, but still the same thing.

Why would the slash still be there?

Thank you

Comment: Is `oo.a` a real directory on your server?

Comment: Yes - I'm trying to get the same look as this link: https://ffm.to/hooklust.owe

Comment: Shaun ,if it's a real directory then you can't remove the trailing slash by RewriteRule because the slash is automatically added by `mod_dir` when a directory is requested . But you can use `DirectorySlash off` in your htaccess to access your directory without using a `/` at the end.